# spark map method throws serialization exception

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, apache-spark

I am new to `Spark` and I have an issue with serialization inside `map` function. Here's some element of the code

```
private Function<Row, String> SparkMap() throws IOException {
        return new Function<Row, String>() {
            public String call(Row row) throws IOException {
                /* some code */
            }
        };
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
        DataFrame df = sqlContext.load(args[0], "com.databricks.spark.avro");

        JavaRDD<String> output = df.javaRDD().map(myClass.SparkMap());
    }
```

here's the error log

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: myPackage.MyClass
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: myPackage.MyClass, value: myPackage.MyClass@281c8380)
    - field (class: myPackage.MyClass$1, name: this$0, type: class myPackage.MyClass)
    - object (class myPackage.MyClass$1, myPackage.MyClass$1@28ef1bc8)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, name: fun$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:312)
    ... 12 more
```

If I declare static the `SparkMap` method, then it runs. How can it be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is pretty explanatory:

```
object not serializable (class: myPackage.MyClass, value: myPackage.MyClass@281c8380)
```

Simply make your `MyClas`s `Serializable` and it will work.

It works as a static because it only takes the function in that case, not the entire `myClass` object